# Custom Dialog Doesn't Show

Tags: android, android-dialog

```
showDialog( DIALOG_CREATEPC ); // called elsewhere

private Dialog addPCDialog()
{
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog( this );

   dialog.setContentView( R.layout.party_createpc );
   dialog.setTitle( "Add PC" );
   ...
   return dialog
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id )
{       
    Dialog dialog;
        switch( id )
        {
            case DIALOG_CREATEPC:
                dialog = addPCDialog();
                break;
            default:
                dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

Am I missing something here? The dialog just doesn't show at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I went through it with the debugger and the program doesn't actually crash. It returns from showDialog just fine. The dialog just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try overriding `onPrepareDialog` instead of `onCreateDialog`

http://androidzteam.com/wpv/?p=44